# The "native_splash_screen" library in Flutter is not working

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I am a beginner developer who has just started learning Flutter.

I am currently trying to apply a splash screen using a library called 'native_splash_screen', which I heard can be easily applied.
I followed the steps in the link below, added the necessary content, ran "Pub get", and entered "flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create" in the terminal.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19

flutter_native_splash:
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false

  color: '#111111'
  image: 'assets/splash_logo.png'
```

However, not only are the applied colors and images not visible, but it also seems that flutter_native_splash itself is not being applied.
The original version of Flutter installed was 3.9.0-15.0.pre.19, and Dart was 3.0.0, but I changed it to the latest stable version 3.7.8 with Dart 2.19.5 because it was not stable.
However, an error appears telling me to upgrade to Dart 3.0.0 when I run Pub get again.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?
I am not sure what the problem is.
I would appreciate it if any Flutter experts could provide an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: try -> flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create    -- if you are running in android 12+ you need to add android_12: after flutter_native_splash: in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to you, the library was applied successfully. Can I ask one more question?
The color and image I entered in the options for flutter_native_splash are not being reflected.
After entering the options, I tried running "flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove" and then "flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create" multiple times. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you testing on Android or iOS, and what version?

Comment: @nuttree I had same issue. I need to run flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create -- every time i changed anything related to flutter_native_splash

Comment: I am testing on an Android 13 emulator and an Android 12 physical device.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you suggested, the colors are being applied correctly now. However, the images are not being reflected. I thought the path might be incorrect, so I tried adding an image with the same path in 'main.dart', and it worked fine. I apologize for continuing to ask questions.

Comment: I have resolved the issue of the image not being displayed after several attempts! Previously, I tried entering the information at the bottom of the pubspec.yaml file, but it didn't work. However, after creating a flutter_native_splash.yaml file in the root directory and working on it, the image is now displaying properly. Thank you all.